# New folder button in Window Explorer toolbar does not work

Tags: windows-7, windows

I have a Sony *Vaio* laptop with  Windows 7 Home Premium 64Bit.

"*New Folder*" button in Windows Explorer does not work nor does the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>
However, I can create a new folder in Explorer by right clicking, selecting *NEW* and selecting *New Folder*.

Do you have any suggestions on how I can fix this?

Comment: It's `Ctrl + Shift + N`, not Ctrl + Alt + N. I assume this doesn't work anyway?

Comment: My mistake.  It doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

Try this first:

**Use the System File Checker tool to troubleshoot missing or corrupted system files on Windows Vista or on Windows 7**

Use the System File Checker tool (SFC.exe) to determine which file is causing the issue, and then replace the file. To do this, follow these steps:

1. Open an elevated command prompt. To do this, click Start, click **All Programs**, click **Accessories**, **right-click Command Prompt**, and then click **Run as administrator**. If you are prompted for an administrator password or for a confirmation, type the password, or click **Allow**.
2. Type the following command, and then press ENTER:
     **sfc /scannow**

*[Source and more information](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929833)*

If the problem persists, post back.

Comment: I did as you suggested.  SFC did not find any problems.

Answer (score -1):

If SFC does not fix the issue, you have 3 other possibilities.

1. Use system restore, pick a restore date before this problem started
2. Create a new user account, log into the new account and see if the folder button works now, if it does, migrate your old user profile over to the new one.
3. Use a Windows 7 install disc with the Upgrade feature to repair the installation

***Back Up Important Data before attempting a repair

> This will show you how to do a repair upgrade install to fix your currently installed Windows 7 and preserve your user accounts, data, programs, and system drivers.
>
> ITEMS THAT WILL BE RESET TO DEFAULT OR AFFECTED:
>   Sounds
>   Services
>   Visual Effects Settings
>   Device Drivers - Be sure to have these handy to reinstall. They do not always remain after the repair (upgrade) install.
>   You may lose the ability to sign on to MSN Messenger, to solve this problem have a look at this thread Unable to sign in to WLM.
>   You may lose your custom themes due to not having permisions set on the old themes. Go to the hidden themes folder at C:/Users/(User-Name)/AppData/Local/Microsoft/Windows/Themes, then Take Ownership of the themes folder and you will now have all your themes back.
>   It has been reported that you may also lose your Media Center gadget after doing the repair install.
>   Windows Updates will need to be checked and reinstalled again.
>
> Warning
>   You can only do a repair install from within Windows 7, you cannot do a repair install at boot or in Safe Mode.
>   You must be logged into Windows 7 in a administrator account to be able to do a repair install.
>   You will not be able to do a repair upgrade install in Safe Mode.
>   The Windows 7 installation DVD that you use to do the repair install with must be the same or newer updated version of Windows 7 (ex: Service Pack level) than the currently installed Windows 7. If the DVD is a older version, then you cannot do a repair install with it.
>   You must have at least 8.87 GB of free space on the hard drive/partition Windows 7 is installed on to do a repair install, more if you have a larger installation.
>
> *Use a key finder and record your currently installed Windows Product Key, On a OEM PC it will be different than the one on the COA sticker.
>   http://sourceforge.net/projects/keyfinder/files/
>
> Here's How:
>
> 1. Start Windows 7, and log on to an administrator account.
> 2. Disable any 3rd party firewall, antivirus, or other security program to avoid it from possibly preventing the repair upgrade installation of Windows 7.
> 3. Place your Windows 7 installation DVD into the DVD drive, while still in Windows 7 (Step 1), and click on the Run setup.exe option in the AutoPlay window from within the currently installed Windows 7.
>      NOTE: If the AutoPlay window does not open, then open the drive folder in Computer and run the setup.exe file.
> 4. If prompted by UAC, then click on Yes.
> 5. Click on the Install Now button to start the installation.
> 6. Uncheck the I want to help make Windows installation better box (unless you would like to), and click on the Go online to get the latest updates for installation option.
> 7. Windows 7 will now check online for and install any available installation updates.
> 8. Check the I accept the license terms box and click on Next
> 9. Click on the Upgrade option.
> 10. The installation of Windows 7 will now begin.
>       NOTE: During the installation process, your screen may flash and computer will restart a few times.
> 11. After the final restart, you will see a black screen with the message "Windows is preparing your computer for the first use"
> 12. Type in your Windows 7 product key number.
> 13. Uncheck the Automatically activate Windows when I'm online box unchecked, then click on the Next button.
>       NOTE: You can activate Windows 7 later after you make sure it is running properly. (See step 20 below)
>       If you chose to automatically activate Windows online when you set up your computer, automatic activation begins trying to activate your copy of Windows three days after you log on for the first time.
> 14. Click on Use recommended settings.
> 15. Select your time zone and set your time and date settings, then click on the Next button.
> 16. Click on the option for your computer's location to select the correct network location type settings to be applied for that location.
>       NOTE: It is best to select "Public Network" for the best security.
> 17. Windows 7 will now prepare your desktop to startup.
> 18. Check to see if you are missing any user files. If you are, then you can copy them from the C:\Windows.old folder
> 19. If everythig checks out in step 18, then you can run Disk Cleanup on the hard drive. You will need to click on the Clean up system files button first, and then check the Files discarded by Windows upgrade, Previous Windows installations, and Windows upgrade log files boxes.
>       NOTE: This will delete the C:\Windows.old folder from step 18 above.
> 20. Refresh your Windows Experience Index (WEI) score.
> 21. All you will need to do now is to activate Windows 7, and make sure that your security programs are enabled again.